# Allocate file on NTFS without zeroing

Tags: winapi, file-io, ntfs

I want to make a tool similar to [zerofree for linux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/zerofree.8.html). I want to do it by allocating a big file without zeroing it, look for nonzero blocks and rewrite them.

With admin privileges it is possible, uTorrent can do this: http://www.netcheif.com/Articles/uTorrent/html/AppendixA_02_12.html#diskio.no_zero , but it's closed source.

Comment: The function you want is `SetFileValidData`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does SetFileValidData doing ? what is the difference with SetEndOfFile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228042/what-does-setfilevaliddata-doing-what-is-the-difference-with-setendoffile)

Comment: Hey, edited my answer and included more appropriate info, so you should take a look if didn't find solution yet.

Comment: If I understand correctly, zerofree does the exact opposite of what you want: _"finds unallocated, non-zeroed blocks in [...] filesystem and fills them with zeroes"_. No? Actually you do want to zero the data for that (which is easiest and fastest by creating some large memory-mappings). You do seem to want to create "holes" in sparse files, though?

Comment: @Damon the point is: 99% of free space could already be zero. I don't want to rewrite it again. It's especially important to prevent growth of dynamic virtual disk images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a tool https://github.com/basinilya/winzerofree . It uses `SetFileValidData()` as @RaymondChen suggested

Comment: Exactly what I needed! It works, too: unlike SDelete, this won't blow up Hyper-V checkpoint sizes by writing sectors that are already zero. If you upload a binary release to GitHub that'll help folks who can't just whip out VS and build it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this answers your question (need), but such a tool already exists. You might have a look at fsutil.exe [Fsutil command line tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788058.aspx). This tool has a huge potential to discover the internal structures of NTFS files and can also create file of any size (without the need to zeroing it manually). Hope that helps.

Comment: you mean `fsutil file createnew` ? The result is zeroed

Comment: Ah, there's another command `fsutil file setvaliddata E:\bigfile 9001` works.

Comment: I get: `Error:  The parameter is incorrect.` when I type `fsutil file setvaliddata E:\bigfile 9001`

Answer (score 0):

You should try [SetFilePointerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365542%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> Note that it is not an error to set the file pointer to a position
>   beyond the end of the file.

So after you create file, call `SetFilePointerEx` and then `SetEndOfFile` or `WriteFile` or `WriteFileEx` and close the file, size should be increased.

**EDIT**

Raymonds suggested [SetValidData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is also good solution, but this requares privileges, so shouldn't be used often by anyone.
My solution is the best on NTFS, because it supports feature known as *initialized size* it means that after using `SetFilePointerEx` data won't be initialized to zeros, but after attempt to read uninitialized data you will receive zeros.

To sum up, if NTFS use `SetFilePointerEx`, if FAT (not very likely) - use `SetValidData`

Comment: But this also zeroes the new bytes.

Comment: @Raymond I didn't test this... Does documentation says so?

Comment: The contents of the extended bytes are undefined. On NTFS (the file system specified in the question), the contents of the extended bytes will be zero for security reasons.

Comment: Thought data always are undefined, could you give a link to docs?

Comment: Since your goal is to ensure that the extended bytes are intentionally uninitialized, the fact that the contents are undefined doesn't meet your goal. Because undefined might mean "zeroed out anyway", which is not what you want. You want something that explicitly leaves the contents uninitialized, which is what SetValidData does.

Comment: @RaymondChen why don't you create an answer?