# How to pre-allocate file on Windows (NTFS) without writing the whole file

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

I have an app that needs to preallocate space for a potentially very file on disk (a few TB). The file should occupy space on disk, such that allocated space can't be used by something else.

Using either [SetFileInformationByHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileinformationbyhandle) and [SetFilePointerEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointerex) with [SetEndOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setendoffile) suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25119897/3806795 does achieve allocation, but there is a big issue: when I write something near the end of the allocated file, Windows seems to start writing the whole actual file to disk (I assume filling the gap between start of the file and the actual write with zeroes).

This results in "System" process using 100% of I/O of the disk until the write is finished, which as you can imagine with multi-terabyte file takes a while even on SSD and wastes its write resource, especially when file is close to the size of the drive itself.

Is there a way to allocate a non-sparse file on Windows 10/11 (NTFS) that doesn't have such a problem? I don't experience such issues with `fallocate` on Linux.

Comment: You need to create a so-called Sparse file. Here's the answer about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686574/47961

Comment: I explicitly mentioned in the question I do NOT want a sparse file and explained why

Comment: Nope. A sparse file is the only option, no matter what you mentioned.

Comment: Depending on your exact use case, you might be able to use [SetFileValidData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilevaliddata).

Comment: >  Nope. A sparse file is the only option, no matter what you mentioned.
It is possible and works great on Linux, is Windows so special?
> Depending on your exact use case, you might be able to use SetFileValidData.
Unfortunately app needs to run under a regular unprivileged user, I saw that one already when doing research on this topic.