# How to get "valid data length" of a file?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ntfs

There is a function to **set** the "valid data length" value: [`SetFileValidData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I didn't find a way to **get** the "valid data length" value.

I want to know about given file if the EOF is different from the VDL, because writing after the VDL in case of `VDL<EOF` will cause a performance penalty as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12241551/2318775).

Comment: Also, the typical "valid data length" is the same as the actual size of the file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not dealing with the typical case...

Comment: Curious, won't you just be including whatever bytes that exist on the disk that are after the end of the file data?

Comment: Then please tell us what case you are dealing with? What are you doing? Why are you doing it? What is the use case? What is the code doing? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the question is simple, I want to **get** this value

Comment: It looks like you are meant to remember the value that you passed when you called `SetFileValidData`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what if I'm not the only one using that file...

Comment: If you have two parties writing to the same file, then they'll need to coordinate their actions in any case.

Comment: I'm given the file from the outside. In case I get a 0 VDL and large EOF
(see the utility "fsutil" with params file createnew) I want to reject the file, to avoid zeroing the whole file on writes to its end.

Comment: I think that this is a fair question that should not have been closed.  I do think though that it would help your cause if you explained the motivation for your asking in an edit to the question.  Perhaps there's another way to solve the underlying problem you face.

Comment: I don't think this information in tracked in any attribute at a FS level and is thus lost when you close the handle. There is no use in keeping this data around after you close the handle because when you reopen the file (from an OS point of view) everything in there is valid. There is no option to open and file and zero-out-what-was-not-zeroed-before. Also this would open a nice attack vector, just look for all files that have these attribute and see if you can get some useful data out of it.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. If the file system has been told the file contains valid data up to X bytes, it believes you and treats that data just like any other file on disk. It's the other case, where a file has been extended but **not** been marked as valid that it has to track - because it's in that case that it needs to know to zero out the blocks at the appropriate time.

Comment: Stop telling me what is the question I want to ask. There is a "property" called valid-data-length, and the question is how can I get it. The answer can be "There is no way", but that doesn't mean that the question is wrong

Comment: Where is your reference that this "property" actually does exist? As far as I can tell, it doesn't. Instead of getting defensive and arguing with people who are trying to help you, start listening to them.

Comment: @Jonathan the msdn docs seem to state that this property is tracked, but I agree that asker would have been better served by providing motivation in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.osr.com/nt-insider/2015-issue1/logical-physical-file-sizes-windows/) page, claims that:

> *there is no mechanism to query the value of the VDL*

So the answer is "you can't".

If you care about performance you can set the VDL to the EOF, but then note that you may allow access old garbage on your disk - the part between those two pointers, that supposed to be zeros if you would access that file without setting the VDL to point the EOF.

Answer (score 2):

Looked into this. No way to get this information via any API, even the e.g. NtQueryInformationFile API (FileEndOfFileInformation only worked with NtSetInformationFile). So finally I read this by manually reading NTFS records. If anyone has a better way, please tell! This also obviously only works with full system access (and NTFS) and might be out of sync with the in-memory information Windows uses.

```cpp
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct NTFSFileRecord
{
    char magic[4];
    unsigned short sequence_offset;
    unsigned short sequence_size;
    uint64 lsn;
    unsigned short squence_number;
    unsigned short hardlink_count;
    unsigned short attribute_offset;
    unsigned short flags;
    unsigned int real_size;
    unsigned int allocated_size;
    uint64 base_record;
    unsigned short next_id;
    //char padding[470];
};

struct MFTAttribute
{
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned char nonresident;
    unsigned char name_lenght;
    unsigned short name_offset;
    unsigned short flags;
    unsigned short attribute_id;
    unsigned int attribute_length;
    unsigned short attribute_offset;
    unsigned char indexed_flag;
    unsigned char padding1;
    //char padding2[488];
};

struct MFTAttributeNonResident
{
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int lenght;
    unsigned char nonresident;
    unsigned char name_length;
    unsigned short name_offset;
    unsigned short flags;
    unsigned short attribute_id;
    uint64 starting_vnc;
    uint64 last_vnc;
    unsigned short run_offset;
    unsigned short compression_size;
    unsigned int padding;
    uint64 allocated_size;
    uint64 real_size;
    uint64 initial_size;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

HANDLE GetVolumeData(const std::wstring& volfn, NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER& vol_data)
{
    HANDLE vol = CreateFileW(volfn.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (vol == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return vol;

    DWORD ret_bytes;
    BOOL b = DeviceIoControl(vol, FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA,
        NULL, 0, &vol_data, sizeof(vol_data), &ret_bytes, NULL);

    if (!b)
    {
        CloseHandle(vol);
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return vol;
}


int64 GetFileValidData(HANDLE file, HANDLE vol, const NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER& vol_data)
{
    BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION hfi;
    BOOL b = GetFileInformationByHandle(file, &hfi);
    if (!b)
        return -1;

    NTFS_FILE_RECORD_INPUT_BUFFER record_in;
    record_in.FileReferenceNumber.HighPart = hfi.nFileIndexHigh;
    record_in.FileReferenceNumber.LowPart = hfi.nFileIndexLow;
    std::vector<BYTE> buf;
    buf.resize(sizeof(NTFS_FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER) + vol_data.BytesPerFileRecordSegment - 1);
    NTFS_FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER* record_out = reinterpret_cast<NTFS_FILE_RECORD_OUTPUT_BUFFER*>(buf.data());
    DWORD bout;
    b = DeviceIoControl(vol, FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD, &record_in,
        sizeof(record_in), record_out, 4096, &bout, NULL);

    if (!b)
        return -1;

    NTFSFileRecord* record = reinterpret_cast<NTFSFileRecord*>(record_out->FileRecordBuffer);

    unsigned int currpos = record->attribute_offset;
    MFTAttribute* attr = nullptr;
    while ( (attr==nullptr ||
        attr->type != 0xFFFFFFFF  )
        && record_out->FileRecordBuffer + currpos +sizeof(MFTAttribute)<buf.data() + bout)
    {
        attr = reinterpret_cast<MFTAttribute*>(record_out->FileRecordBuffer + currpos);
        if (attr->type == 0x80
            && record_out->FileRecordBuffer + currpos + attr->attribute_offset+sizeof(MFTAttributeNonResident)
                < buf.data()+ bout)
        {
            if (attr->nonresident == 0)
                return -1;

            MFTAttributeNonResident* dataattr = reinterpret_cast<MFTAttributeNonResident*>(record_out->FileRecordBuffer
                + currpos + attr->attribute_offset);
            return dataattr->initial_size;
        }
        currpos += attr->length;
    } 

    return -1;
}

[...]
    NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER vol_data;
    HANDLE vol = GetVolumeData(L"\\??\\D:", vol_data);
    if (vol != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int64 vdl = GetFileValidData(alloc_test->getOsHandle(), vol, vol_data);
        if(vdl>=0) { [...] }
        [...]
    }
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused as to what "valid data length" actually *means*. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228042).

Basically, while `SetEndOfFile` lets you increase the length of a file quickly, and allocates the disk space, if you skip to the (new) end-of-file to write there, all the additionally allocated disk space would need to be overwritten with zeroes, which is kind of slow.

`SetFileValidData` lets you *skip* that zeroing-out. You're telling the system, "I am OK with whatever is in those disk blocks, get on with it". (This is why you need the `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME` priviledge, as it could reveal priviledged data to unpriviledged users if you don't overwrite the data. Users *with* this priviledge can access the raw drive data anyway.)

In either case, you have set the new effective size of the file. (Which you *can* read back.) What, exactly, *should* a seperate "read file valid data" report back? `SetFileValidData` *told* the system that whatever is in those disk blocks *is* "valid"...

---

Different approach of explanation:

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mentions that the "valid data length" *is* being tracked; the purpose for this is for the system to know which range (from end-of-valid-data to end-of-file) it still needs to *zero out*, in the context of `SetEndOfFile`, when necessary (e.g. you closing the file). **You** don't need to read back this value, because the only way it could be *different* from the actual file *size* is because you, yourself, did change it via the aforementioned functions...

Comment: I am well aware of the meaning of the VDL.
In my scenario, it makes perfect sense to query it, as I want to *reject* files provided to me with VDL 0 and large EOF. (Remember, VDL isn't always set by me + it may have changed since last set using SetFileValidData, due to writes near file's end.)

Comment: @avim: Putting that information into the question itself would have gone a *long* way towards not getting it closed as "unclear", and getting to-the-point answers. That being said, I don't think there is a way to read that property, short of relying on undocumented behaviour. I am also still not sure about your use case; the available documentation on VDL is not clear on the semantics in a case like you are describing, so you might *already* be assuming too much.

Answer (score 0):

The `SetValidData` (according to MSDN) can be used to create for example a large file without having to write to the file. For a database this will allocate a (contiguous) storage area.

As a result, it seems the file size on disk will have changed without any data having been written to the file.

By implication, any `GetValidData` (which does not exist) just returns the size of the file, so you can use `GetFileSize` which returns the "valid" file size.

Comment: `GetFileSize` returns the size by the EOF position, not the VDL

Comment: The EOF position IS the file size and IS the VDL.

Comment: Please read my links in the question, you will see that it is not the case